# Wifi roaming with same SSID on two TP-Link access points

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have two Wifi TP-Link access points with the same SSID:

```
$ sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -sGoOut
                            SSID BSSID             RSSI CHANNEL HT CC SECURITY (auth/unicast/group)
                           GoOut e8:48:b8:57:01:61 -74  44      Y  -- WPA2(PSK,SAE/AES/AES)
                           GoOut e8:48:b8:57:01:5f -71  3       Y  -- WPA2(PSK,SAE/AES/AES)
                           GoOut 00:5f:67:9a:e2:64 -47  10      Y  -- WPA2(PSK,SAE/AES/AES)
                           GoOut 00:5f:67:9a:e2:66 -45  48      Y  -- WPA2(PSK,SAE/AES/AES)
```

You can see the `:e2:64` is way stronger signal at my current location, however OSX wouldn't switch the network event after minutes:

```
$ sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Resources/airport -I
     agrCtlRSSI: -75
     agrExtRSSI: 0
    agrCtlNoise: -92
    agrExtNoise: 0
          state: running
        op mode: station
     lastTxRate: 260
        maxRate: 144
lastAssocStatus: 0
    802.11 auth: open
      link auth: wpa3-sae
          BSSID: e8:48:b8:57:1:61
           SSID: GoOut
            MCS: 3
        channel: 44,80
```

You can see it still stays connected to the network with -75 RSSI.

I also tried setting `Strongest` JoinMode as described in [How to enable faster WiFi Roaming with Mac OS X & Airport base stations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66919/how-to-enable-faster-wifi-roaming-with-mac-os-x-airport-base-stations) however that had no effect.

Comment: Most devices won't switch until the first signal is lost entirely. Though it's not in my area of expertise, I suspect this is what mesh is designed to eliminate.

Comment: I understand that Mesh solves a little bit different thing - it repeats already existing wifi network - however I have the whole place covered by LAN wires, so it doesn't make sense to repeat WIFI network as that couldn't be as fast just by the fact that it doesn't go through wires.